# Understanding the dlm package in r

Tags: r

I am trying to forecast a monthly time series using the R package **dlm**. I am reading through the vignette and have a few questions. Regarding the forecasting of the `UKgas` data I see

```
dlmGas <- dlmModPoly() + dlmModSeas(4)
```

the 4 is the quaterly format of the series, so for a monthly series, should I use `dlmModSeas(12)` instead?

Also for the functions

```
diag(W(dlmGas))[2:3] <- exp(x[1:2])
V(dlmGas) <- exp(x[3])
```

what are these numbers and how are they chose? also how would this look different for a monthly series?

Comment: I don't know about this package,  but check out the *forecast* package, it's very very good.

Answer (score 4):

To the first question: I think dlmModSeas(12) is correct for monthly data. And if you execute in R the command:

```
dlmModPoly() + dlmModSeas(12)
```

and look at the matrix `W` you see, that still only the second and the third diagonal elements are different from zero.

I suppose the `diag(W(dlmGas))[2]` refers to the system noise variance of the trend component (*dlmModPoly()*)
and `diag(W(dlmGas))[3]` to the system noise variance of the seasonal component (*dlmModSeas(12)*)

So, as I understand it, increasing the number of seasons does not increase the diagonal elements of `W` to be estimated.

Comment: Thanks for the help, so I guess I don't have to change anything for the yearly data, except for the dlmModSeas(4)?

Comment: If my answer was of any use to you, it would be nice if you accepted it. Thanks.